# How a file actually gets deleted in java?

Tags: java, file

Just curious to know about the internal mechanism of file delete operation in Java. I was looking into the source code of `java.io.File`. 
When we call the delete() function, it actually calls the `java.io.FileSystem` 's abstract delete() method and based on OS (i.e. Unix/Windows) the actual delete is being performed. I was analyzing into the `java.io.UnixFileSystem`'s delete() method and found this -

```
public boolean delete(File f) {
    // Keep canonicalization caches in sync after file deletion
    // and renaming operations. Could be more clever than this
    // (i.e., only remove/update affected entries) but probably
    // not worth it since these entries expire after 30 seconds
    // anyway.
    cache.clear();
    javaHomePrefixCache.clear();
    return delete0(f);
}
private native boolean delete0(File f);
```

So it actually performs some cache clearance and finally calls the native delete0() method. 
I was wondering how actually the delete operation happens? Does it internally call the `rm` or `rm -f` command or anything else to delete the file?

Comment: It invokes native code, as it must, because every operating system implements delete. On posix systems, I believe it calls [`unlink(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink).

Comment: Files are not deleted by Java. They are deleted by the OS.

Comment: 'Based on OS (i.e. Unix/Windows) the actual delete is being performed' is exactly correct. So what is your question?